# Trabajar con archivos csv de 2GB o más

Tags: python, base-de-datos, csv, ciencia-de-datos

Quería preguntarles por donde se puede descargar, o bajar el python, documentos .csv de un tamaño igual o mayor a 2GB. El caso es que he creado un documento de esas dimensiones con Fake y luego he intentado leerlos con pandas (con y sin chuncks), dask ray y mobin y cuando trato de usar funciones como head (con pandas tras convertirlo en dataframe) tienden a dar error y querría saber como resolverlo:

Las líneas que he escrito son:

```
f=open("data.csv","r")
print(f.read())
f.close()
```

Luego para pandas use estos dos:

```
df=pd.read_csv("lite_People_data.csv")
df2=pd.read_csv("lite_People_data.csv",chunksize=1000)
```

Luego use las otras librerías, aún sabiendo que con las anteriores lo más probable es que me den errores como lee documentos de tales dimensiones con estos métodos y como modificar dichos documentos con pandas, dask, ray o mobin de forma relativamente rápida.

Un saludo

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. ¿QUé problema tienes? No hay una limitación "definida", aunque sí puede haber límites _duros_ en alguna implementación específica de alguna librería (o de tu código). Podríás por favor [edit] tu pregunta y describir tu problema? QUé código usas, qué error sale, por qué dices que 2GB?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!